# how to remove duplicate elements from an array of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
"2017-08-31":["5948a0dd21146a43fdcfef5a","5948a0dd21146a43fdcfef5a"]
"2017-08-22":["5948a0dd21146a43fdcfef5a"]
"2017-08-09":["59461ceae6179b19403c6a19","59461ceae6179b19403c6a19"]
"2017-08-08":["59461ceae6179b19403c6a19","59461ceae6179b19403c6a19"]
```

I have an array like this, key is a date and multiple value associated with that date, but I need unique value with that key.how to do that ? 
I've tried with **array_unique** but no luck!

Comment: Can you show the result which is expected?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: As above, you need to define your problem better to get help - it looks like you could just take the 1st result from all the subarrays, but that might not be the case - you need to clarify

Comment: `"2017-08-31":["5948a0dd21146a43fdcfef5a"]
"2017-08-22":["5948a0dd21146a43fdcfef5a"]
"2017-08-09":["59461ceae6179b19403c6a19"]
"2017-08-08":["59461ceae6179b19403c6a19"]`  @Neodan

Comment: so each data key will contain a single element array? Will your source array always contain duplicates, or could a date key contain an array with non duplicate values? If so, which value gets kept? Or perhaps your output could contain multiple elements per key if they are unique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) together.

```
<?php
$a = json_decode('{"2017-08-31":["5948a0dd21146a43fdcfef5a","5948a0dd21146a43fdcfef5a"],
                   "2017-08-22":["5948a0dd21146a43fdcfef5a"],
                   "2017-08-09":["59461ceae6179b19403c6a19","59461ceae6179b19403c6a19"],
                   "2017-08-08":["59461ceae6179b19403c6a19","59461ceae6179b19403c6a19"]}', true);

echo json_encode(array_map("array_unique", $a));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = your array   
$array = array_map(function($val){return array_unique($val);}, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You better do this using SQL if it's possible. Otherwise, you can try this:

```
$array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: Works like magic!